# How to store server auto generated value to Primary key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, oledb

I was working on an application that uses sql server database. I the auto generated value for the primary key to be stored into dataset. I was using the below code. But the problem is my primary key column ie, *ProdNum* is readonly. For that it won't allow to set that value. How can I overcome this?

---

```
Private Sub OnRowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
        ' Include a variable and a command to retrieve the identity value from the Access database.
        Dim newID As Integer = 0
        Dim idCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", args.Command.Connection(), args.Command.Transaction)
        If args.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
            ' Retrieve the identity value and store it in the ProductIDNum column.
            newID = CInt(idCMD.ExecuteScalar())
            ' place in the identity column of the local table in the dataset
            'args.Row("ProdNum") = newID
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What you've posted is a bit vague, however, what do you mean by "read only"? Do you mean it is an `IDENTITY` column? If you are generating the ID for a row elsewhere (for example in the application), then don't declare your column as an `IDENTITY` column. Or, have an `IDENTITY` column and an additional "SomeOtherID" column. `IDENTITY` is designed so that you don't provide a value. If you are providing one, then you're (probably) not using it correctly

Comment: There is not enough detail here to understand what you are trying to do. I think you are very confused about how the identity property works.

Comment: It's an identity column. My how will get the server generated id to my dataset?

Comment: @SeanLange I want to get the identity value generated for that row after update() is called

Comment: You could use `OUTPUT` ([OUTPUT Clause (Tranasct-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). However, after an `UPDATE` the ID won't change, so not sure why it's needed to be fed back.

Comment: You don't do that with @@identity. In fact you shouldn't be using that anyway but that is another topic. That will get the last generated identity value which does not happen on an update. You just need to get the value from the row that you updated...and yes that column should be read only in your grid.

Comment: @SeanLange yep realised that just after I posted the comment initially, hence the edited comment. :)

Comment: @Larnu when will the id get generated? after commit only?

Comment: The identity value is created when the row is inserted into the database. Since you are updating an existing row the value already exists, you just need to grab it from the DataRow in your grid.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry for the confusion. I'm running an insert command. I was referring to adapter.update() method that will get called to run the command.

Comment: @SeanLange beat me to it. When you run an `UPDATE` against a row with an  `IDENTITY` column, the value of the `IDENTITY` column doesn't change.

Comment: `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are very different things! Ok, in that case, seems my statement in regards to `OUTPUT` **is** relevant...

Comment: You are executing an INSERT statement when you update a row in the grid? You need to provide a LOT more information here. We can't see your screen and we don't know what you are trying to do. As it sits right now this question is all over the place. You might want to start here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Larnu You got whicha update() method I'm referring? not the database update. It's oledbdataadapter.update() function used to execute the commands

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can do this using `OleDb` (you can't for Access, but that's a different OLE DB provider) but if you use `SqlClient` then there's no need to handle any events because you can simply tack a `SELECT`onto your `INSERT` in the `CommandText` of your adapter's `InsertCommand`, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO Thing (Name, Description) VALUES (@Name, @Description);
SELECT ThingId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

That's always worked for me.